# How to pass data from view controller in one storyboard to another view controller in second storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I have a view controller, where is my:

```
@IBOutlet weak var schoolNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var schoolLogoImageView: UIImageView!
```

When we launch the app, we can choose the photo and name what we need and it will display on 1 view controller, which is in first storyboard. After this, I need to know, how to pass this data to another view controller in second storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            if SchoolsPreHomeViewController.screenPresnted {
                store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .appHome, direction: .forwardNoAnimation))
            } else {
                if let imageStringUrl = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "schoolLogo") as? String, let url = URL(string: imageStringUrl) {
                    schoolLogoImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
                }
                schoolNameLabel.text = MultiTenancyManager.shared.homeScreenTitle
            }
```

In the end, it should be something like this: We choose photo and name, going to home menu, where is the button, on which I should tap and open view controller with the data from 1 view controller with this picture and name. I've tried something with prepareforsegue, but not sure understand about it.

Comment: I would help myself running a search for MYSELF to see if there are similar topics if I were you.

Comment: Use prepareForSegue:sender: